# Integrating React in a web application and build in Jenkins

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, jakarta-ee

We are integrating React into our existing web application and facing issues when I build react components using our Jenkins build server.

**Steps I did**

- Since Jenkins deletes the working directory everytime when build starts I moved node_modules outside the project. I am referring to the node_modules using webpackconfig.js - "resolve" and "resolveLoader" options. Example snippet below.

```html
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'); // for extracting generated CSS to external file(s)
    const path = require('path');
    const nodeModulesPath = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/';
module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
 resolveLoader: {
   modules: (argv.mode === 'production' ? [nodeModulesPath] : ['./node_modules/'])
  },
```

- Installed webpack and webpack-cli globally to trigger "npm run build" through ant command.
- Set NODE_PATH (through jenkins script) to the node_modules folder that is located outside the project.

When I start Jenkins, I get the following error

```html
[echo]  NPM NODE PATH Set completed
[exec] /usr/local/lib
[exec] ├── npm@5.6.0
[exec] ├── webpack@4.16.5
[exec] └── webpack-cli@2.1.5
[exec] 
[echo]  NPM run deploy starts /apps/jenkins_slave/tools/web/extensions/custom/
[echo]        
[exec] 
[exec] > markethub-plus-ui@1.0.0 deploy /apps/jenkins_slave/tools/web/extensions/custom/
[exec] > webpack --mode production --display-error-details
[exec] 
[exec] /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack.js:243
[exec]     throw err;
[exec]     ^
[exec] 
[exec] Error: Cannot find module 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
[exec]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
[exec]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
[exec]     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
[exec]     at require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
[exec]     at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/jenkins_slave/tools/web/extensions/custom/webpack.config.js:1:87)
```

When I log into the Jenkins build server directly and run from bash this works. I get the above error only when I start the build through Jenkins user console.

Has anyone tried this before? Or what is the correct way to integrate React in this case? Please let me know your thoughts.

Cheers.